# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Hi all I am getting a exception while working with support lib. I know lot of question and answer are available in SO but no one work for me

```
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:147)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at com.devicemonitor.DeviceMonitorActivity.onCreate(DeviceMonitorActivity.java:29)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-27 11:58:15.470: E/AndroidRuntime(19609):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What i have did is like this - I have android-support-v7-appcompat.jar as well as android-support-v4.jar in android java build path.

In some answer in SO suggested that unchecked Android dependencies in java build path i tried it also but nothing is working for me.

In my gen folder there are two package one for goole-play-service-lib and another for my project , and in my project package under gen folder only trwo file is there R.java and BuildCOnfig.java.  Anybody have any suggestion please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the support.v7.appcompat as a library project in your workspace and attach it with your project.

Try this,it will work for sure.
if you still face any issue, do comment.

Comment: You mean to say add this as lib  <sdk>/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/

Comment: <sdk>\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

This one i am refering to.

Comment: After importing, do you know how to add this in your project or should i explain all the steps.?

Comment: I tried it . appcompat it self showing error in folder value-v21 theme_base.xml in this line         <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable</item>

Comment: Yes this is because your compiler is set bellow 21 api.

Go to properties> android> mark apilevel 21 as checked save it then clean this library project.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for you help i am installing android 5.0 api, then i will compile appcompat with api 21, and then let you know.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and i imported the library and it shows up in Referenced Libraries folder but not sure what to do from there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to just delete your appcompat  and re-import it to eclipse and change its android built property to highest api configuration. Clean your project, copy-paste R file in gen package and change project build path to highest api level like api-21.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In "android-support-v7-appcompat" project:

```
-Delete “android-support-v7-appcompat” from Package explorer.
-Import again and check “Copy into workspace”
-In Properties -> Android -> in Project build target, uncheck Android 2.2 and check Android 4.1.2
-In Java build path, uncheck if you have any .jar library, and uncheck the Dependence
```

and finally this is what you need to do.
[image]

Comment: I tried it . appcompat it self showing error in folder value-v21 theme_base.xml in this line         <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable</item>

Comment: If this lib itself showing error how can i used it as library. Please suggest me .

Comment: I even dont have a folder value-v21 in my aapcompat :O

Comment: than may be you should download a new appcompat :|

Comment: @dilshad Ahmed change the properties as i explained, it will remove this error.

Comment: after serching a little I came to know that it is may be because compiler is set below 21API level.Change it in your properties: android

Comment: yeah yeah thats what I get too

Comment: @Zoain : dude u dont have a folder for v21 coz ur appcompact lib. is old. you need to download a new one.

Comment: Yeah @Nitesh I knew it. :( I have too

Answer (score 0):

Try to import v7 appcompat with resources for your project rather than directly using .jar file.

Here is the link for importing appcompat with resources - https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

If you come across problems in your project after importing v7 appcompat, cross check target sdk version in manifest and set the target sdk version to the latest sdk api version.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems wider, but in my particular case it was caused by clashing between the following dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
```