# android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-appcompat

I am using IntelliJ and my project has appcompat (`C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`) as a dependency, the appcompat has `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`. In my main project i didn't `import/include` both the `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`

The problem is that everytime i run my app i am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
    at com.******.*****.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
```

I have tried almost all the answers on Stack Overflow but with no luck. Do anyone know where i am going wrong?

[image: Project Structure 1] [image: Project Structure 2] [image: Project Structure 3] [image: Project Structure 4]

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ's build system, ant, or gradle?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @Jared, no. IntelliJ can build Android projects natively using its own build system, or it can use Gradle, or it can use Ant.

Comment: I do not know where my comment went but Intellij(he is most likely using Android Studio) does use Gradle. That is what I saying.

Comment: Sure, but I deduced he wasn't using Gradle from these clues: One, he mentions the absolute path to the library. He wouldn't do this if he was using Gradle. Two, in a comment to the answer below, he says he isn't using Gradle.

Comment: @SkyKelsey, i have added image links of my project structure, maybe this might give a good understanding of my problem. Thank you for your responses :)

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
```

**`NoClassDefFoundError`** indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the *.class*.

Please add this in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: My project is not gradle built, i tried the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164539/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rstyleab?rq=1 but no luck. Please assist

Comment: You need to tell us how you are building your project, otherwise we can't advise you on how to fix the error. See my comment on your question.

Comment: @SkyKelsey i have edited my question by including the screenshots of my project structure