# If i use ActionBarActivity I am getting fatal Exception

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity

If I use ActionBarActivity instead of Activity I am getting fatal exception. I added support library  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Here is my exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at com.yemensoft.Onyx.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ActionBarActivity is currently deprecated, you should be using AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Yes It is depreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using ActionBarActivity from now on, since, as mentioned by Thomaz there, it was deprecated a few months ago.

As for the AppCompatActivity, refer to this link: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/example-usage-of-appcompatactivity-in-android/

There are few changes you need to make, but nothing complex, and it's usage is basically the same.

Comment: Mohr, I updated the support library to  22.2.1. Now extended SecondActivity to AppCompatActivity but still same error

Comment: That's probably an issue with the lib imports.. First, check if you have both the appcompat v4 and v7 imported in your project, after that, if you're using eclipse, you're most likely pointing directly to the appcompat's JAR file, instead, add it as a library and use that library in your project. (for this second part, there's another SO question here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164539/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rstyleab ).

Comment: Either it's one of the situations I pointed above, or it's something like duplicated references to the appcompat. Either way, please confirm the IDE you're using and how you've imported appcompat to use in your project.